# SnowdogApps Menu error on Magento EE 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, magento2-enterprise

I have installed a menu module from SnowdogApps from here https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-menu. Install went fine, all tables were created successfully, but when I create a new menu in the admin, I get the following error:

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'v.entity_id' in 'on clause', query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`parent_id`, `v`.`value` AS `name` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `v` ON v.entity_id = e.entity_id AND v.store_id = 0 
            AND v.attribute_id = 45 WHERE (e.level > 0) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) ORDER BY `e`.`level` ASC, `e`.`position` ASC

Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'v.entity_id' in 'on clause'

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'v.entity_id' in 'on clause', query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`parent_id`, `v`.`value` AS `name` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `v` ON v.entity_id = e.entity_id AND v.store_id = 0 
            AND v.attribute_id = 45 WHERE (e.level > 0) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) ORDER BY `e`.`level` ASC, `e`.`position` ASC
```

I found out that the field in catalog_category_entity_varchar to which it is referring to (entity_id) does not exist in Magento Enterprise Edition and is replaced by row_id.

Where should I reflect this change in the module's code?